# Problems with reading a .wav file with c++

Tags: c++, wav

I'm having problems with reading a WAVE file. I'm currently using this tutorial (http://rogerchansdigitalworld.blogspot.de/2010/05/how-to-read-wav-format-file-in-c.html) to get into that stuff.
So here's a part of my code:

```
void loadWaveFile(char *fname, WavData *ret) {
FILE* fp = fopen(fname,"rb");

if (fp)  {
    char id[5];
    unsigned long size;
    short format_tag, channels, block_align, bits_per_sample;
    unsigned long format_length, sample_rate, avg_bytes_sec, data_size; 
    fread(id, sizeof(char),4,fp); 
    id[4] = '\0';

    if(!strcmp(id,"RIFF")) { 
        fread(&size, sizeof(unsigned long),1,fp); 
        fread(id, sizeof(char),4,fp); 
        id[4] = '\0';

        if(!strcmp(id,"WAVE")) { 

            fread(id,sizeof(char),4,fp); 
            fread(&format_length, sizeof(unsigned long),1,fp);
            fread(&format_tag, sizeof(short),1,fp);
            fread(&channels, sizeof(short),1,fp);
            fread(&sample_rate, sizeof(unsigned long),1,fp);
            fread(&avg_bytes_sec, sizeof(unsigned long),1,fp);
            fread(&block_align, sizeof(short),1,fp);
            fread(&bits_per_sample, sizeof(short),1,fp); 
            fread(id,sizeof(char),4,fp); 
            fread(&data_size, sizeof(unsigned long),1,fp); 

            ret->size = data_size/sizeof(short);
            ret->data =(short*) malloc(data_size);
            fread(ret->data, sizeof(short), ret->size,fp);

        }
        else {
            std::cout<<"Error: RIFF Datei, aber keine wave Datei\n";
        }
    }
    else {
        std::cout<<"Error: keine RIFF Datei\n";
    }
}
else {
    std::cout<<"Error: keine Datei ausgewaehlt\n";
}
fclose(fp);
```

It is almost the same as shown in the link.
My main problem is the second if-statement. When I'm running the code, it reads "fmt " instead of "WAVE". Seems like it skips the "WAVE" part and jumps directly into the "fmt " part. Anyone has an idea what's wrong here?
Here's also a detailed description of a WAVE file http://mathmatrix.narod.ru/Wavefmt.html

Thanks!

Comment: You're assuming that `sizeof(unsigned long) == 4` - this isn't guaranteed (it can't be less than 4 bytes but may be larger).  It'd be easier to just read the first 12 bytes of the file then test `if (strncmp(buf, "RIFF", 4) == 0 && strncmp(buf+8, "WAVE", 4) == 0)`

Comment: Just out of curiosity, have you looked into using a library?  It would be much easier to use libsndfile. (http://www.mega-nerd.com/libsndfile/)

Comment: @csnate libsndfile has a license which may be problematic for commercial products.  I think it'd be unusable for iOS apps too.  (Not suggesting you shouldn't recommend existing libraries, just that its worth mentioning if they have non-liberal licenses.)

Comment: use `<stdint.h>` where you need fixed or minimum size types.